# Find computer geographic location python

Tags: python, gis

I would like to be able to track my computers geographic location. So far I have managed to implement one strategy, which is to use my ip address in order to get a geographic location. Unfortunately, this method is not precise enough. I would like to be able to track my computer with a precision similar to what Iphones can do, house and street number. From reading around I know that one can still make use of Wifi, Cellphone and GPS to triangulate your current position. With other services like google maps out there, I know that it definitely is possible. I was just not successful in finding anything that I could implement into python code.

So to summarize, I would appreciate any useful suggestions that allow somebody to find the geographic location of a computer; without the ip address strategy. Thanks!

Edit 1:
If you are interested to see what the code looks like so far, here the sample:

```
import urllib2
import json


url = 'http://ipinfo.io/json'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
IP_Info = response.read()
IP_List = json.loads(IP_Info)

#info = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
ip = IP_List['ip']
loc = IP_List['loc']
print ip
print loc
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information. Is this a web application? Are you using the browser's "share location" feature or using a GeoIP service? What have you tried (show us your code). If you want to avoid downvotes, you need to show us the code you've tried.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know much about this topic, reason why I am asking. All I have tried is the use of the ip, as shown above, however this is not precise enough. I would like to get better results, how, I have no idea. I was thinking of using google maps to improve my results, as a first step. I would however also like that the program tries different strategies, so that if one fails, maybe the next works out better.

Answer (score 1):

The way cellphones get your location via Wi-Fi is proprietary to Google/Apple. They often sample Wi-Fi access points while a device is outdoors and has a GPS lock to associate that AP with a location. You'll have to use proprietary services to get that level of detail from just an IP.

If you want a precise location using a physical GPS device, you can use `gpsd` and its python bindings like so:

```
from gps import gps, WATCH_ENABLE   

gps = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
lock = False
while not lock:
    report = gps.next()
    # 3D Fix
    if report['class'] == 'TPV' and report['mode'] == 3:
        print(report.lon)
        print(report.lat)
        print(report.alt)
        print(report.speed)
        print(report.track)
        print(report.climb)
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: syntax error: bare `import` statement

Comment: @knia I had a stray import. I fixed the answer.